# spring boot testing - passing commandline arguments

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have integration test with annotations on it:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("integration")
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader, classes = [MyApplication])
@IntegrationTest(["server.port=0"])
```

I can pass for example server.port property to test context, but is there any way to pass commandline arguments? My application is started like this normally:

```
public static final void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AnkaraCollectorApplication.class, args);
}
```

and I want to pass some args to test context. Is there any property for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven, you can pass test JVM args inside the failsafe plugin:

`<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          ...
          <configuration>

            <argLine> whatever you want: -DhelloWorld=Test </argLine>
          </configuration>
          ...`

You can also set this JVM arguments based on the maven profile that your are executing:

`<profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <!-- Development JVM arguments -->
            <test-arguments>-Dhello=true</test-arguments>
            <!-- Default environment -->
            <environment>develop</environment>
        </properties>
  </profile>
    ...
    <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          ...
          <configuration>

            <argLine>${test-arguments}</argLine>
          </configuration>
          ...`

Comment: But I need to pass commandline arguments. I use some library in which there is spring ApplicationListener and this listener is using commandline arguments from ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent.getArgs(). I have to do something that getArgs() will return my arguments.

Comment: The problem here is the integration test doesn't call your Application.main method. It is only inspecting the annotations. Where are you using those command arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting inside the test class:

```
static {
    System.setProperty("key", "value");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In spring 2X use:

```
mvn clean install -Darg1=val1 -Darg2=val2
```

and you will never get "Could not resolve placeholder" while using @Value property injection